# Imprimir array 2D que omita líneas en blanco en java

Tags: java, array, bucles

Es mi primer post, así que disculpas anticipadas si hago algo mal.

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa donde tengo un array 2D donde se almacena la información de una serie de alumnos(Ciudad,Estudios previos,Edad,Ciclo).

He hecho un menú, donde se le dan varias opciones al usuario, una de ellas, que es donde tengo el problema, pide al usuario que introduzca una ciudad y el programa imprime todos los datos de esos alumnos que tengan coincidencia con lo que ha introducido el usuario(es decir, aunque se introduzca parcialmente el nombre de una ciudad, o incluso solo una letra, se liste lo coincidente).

He conseguido que lo imprima, pero me imprime líneas vacías en las posiciones donde la ciudad del array no tiene ninguna coincidencia con lo que se introduce.

Os dejo imagen de como me sale la tabla con este código.

[image: Resultado de la impresión.]

Os copio el código:

```
case 4: //Mostrar datos por ciudad
                    System.out.println("TODO: Mostrar datos por ciudad");
                    System.out.println("Introduce una ciudad a buscar:");
                    String ciudad = input.next().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
                        System.out.printf("%-25s", header[i]);//Imprimo el nombre de las columnas
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
                        System.out.printf("%-25s", "_________________________");//Cree la separación de guiones
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++)
                                if (data[i][0].toLowerCase().contains(ciudad))
                                    System.out.printf("%-25s", data[i][j]);
                                    System.out.println();
                                    coincidencia = true;
                        }
                    if(coincidencia==false){
                        System.out.println("Lo sentimos, no encontramos ningún alumno para la ciudad introducida.");
                    }
                break;
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: Revisa cómo funciona ese método `contains` que usas y cómo podrías usar `equals`. Lo otro, te faltan llaves en el `if` y en ese caso sólo va a incluir la primera instrucción dentro, el resto se ejecutarán siempre

Comment: El cerrar la llave como te mencionaron te solucionará el problema de los espacios en blanco.

Comment: Ya he puesto la llave pero sigue imprimiéndolo igual. Creo que sé porqué lo hace pero no sé como solucionarlo, al ejecutar el bucle y entrar en el if , si cumple la condición imprime los datos y si no lo encuentra no lo imprime pero deja el espacio del array vacío. Entiendo que tendré que ordenar las filas para que se coloquen las que tienen contenido primero y deje las que no lo tienen abajo. Seguiré probando a ver si lo arreglo.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he conseguido!. He cambiado el System.out.printf por el System.out.format y me ha funcionado.
Al usar el format en vez de usar un bucle anidado, le da formato a todas las posiciones de la fila de golpe con un solo for .

El código es este:

```
case 4: //Mostrar datos por ciudad
                    System.out.println("TODO: Mostrar datos por ciudad");
                    System.out.println("Introduce una ciudad a buscar:");
                    String ciudad = input.next().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
                        System.out.printf("%-25s", header[i]);//Imprimo el nombre de las columnas
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
                        System.out.printf("%-25s", "_________________________");//Cree la separación de guiones
                    }
                        System.out.println();
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                if (data[i][0].toLowerCase().contains(ciudad)) {
                                    System.out.format("%-25s %-25s %-25s %-25s %n",data[i]);
                                    //System.out.println();
                                    coincidencia = true;
                                }
                        }
                    System.out.println();
                    if(coincidencia==false){
                        System.out.println("Lo sentimos, no encontramos ningún alumno para la ciudad introducida.");
                    }
                break;
```

Y así es como me ha quedado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]